# How to find two elements of the same array that contain all vowels

Tags: ruby, nested-loops

I want to iterate a given array, for example:

```
["goat", "action", "tear", "impromptu", "tired", "europe"]
```

I want to look at all possible pairs.

The desired output is a new array, which contains all pairs, that combined contain all vowels. Also those pairs should be concatenated as one element of the output array:

```
["action europe", "tear impromptu"]
```

I tried the following code, but got an error message:

```
No implicit conversion of nil into string.
```

```rb
def all_vowel_pairs(words)
  pairs = []

  (0..words.length).each do |i|                       # iterate through words
    (0..words.length).each do |j|                   # for every word, iterate through words again
      pot_pair = words[i].to_s + words[j]         # build string from pair
      if check_for_vowels(pot_pair)               # throw string to helper-method.
        pairs << words[i] + " " + words[j]      # if gets back true, concatenade and push to output array "pairs"
      end
    end
  end
  pairs
end

# helper-method to check for if a string has all vowels in it
def check_for_vowels(string)
  vowels = "aeiou"
  founds = []
  string.each_char do |char|
    if vowels.include?(char) && !founds.include?(char)
      founds << char
    end
  end
  if founds.length == 5
    return true
  end
  false
end
```

Comment: This sounds like homework. If so, read "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/128421)".

Comment: hi @theTinMan yes this is homework, thank´s for the article, i´ll respect that in the future!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains two errors, one of which is causing the error message.

`(0..words.length)` loops from 0 to 6 . `words[6]` however does not exist (arrays are zero-based), so you get nil. Replacing by `(0..words.length-1)` (twice) should take care of that.

You will get every correct result twice, once as `"action europe"` and once as `"europe action"`. This is caused by looping too much, going two times over every combination. Replace the second loop from `(0..words.length-1)` to `(i..words.length-1)`.

This cumbersome bookkeeping of indexes is boring and leads to mistakes very often. This is why Ruby programmers often prefer more hassle-free methods (like `combination` as in other answers), avoiding indexes altogether.

Comment: hey @steenslag thx for the reply! I was able to fix it with one of the solutions provided above, but its cool that with your help I was able to make my original approach work.
Yeah I have to get a lot better at using those built-in methods!

Comment: Use built-in methods as much as possible. For the most part they're closer to the metal so they'll run a lot faster.

Answer (score 3):

The following code is intended to provide an efficient way to construct the desired array when the number of words is large. Note that, unlike the other answers, it does not make use of the method [Array#combination](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-combination).

The first part of the section *Explanation* (below) provides an overview of the approach taken by the algorithm. The details are then filled in.

**Code**

```
require 'set'

VOWELS = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
VOWELS_SET = VOWELS.to_set

def all_vowel_pairs(words)
  h = words.each_with_object({}) {|w,h| (h[(w.chars & VOWELS).to_set] ||= []) << w}
  h.each_with_object([]) do |(k,v),a|
    vowels_needed = VOWELS_SET-k
    h.each do |kk,vv|
      next unless kk.superset?(vowels_needed)
      v.each {|w1| vv.each {|w2| a << "%s %s" % [w1, w2] if w1 < w2}}
    end
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
words = ["goat", "action", "tear", "impromptu", "tired", "europe", "hear"]

all_vowel_pairs(words)
  #=> ["action europe", "hear impromptu", "impromptu tear"]
```

**Explanation**

For the given example the steps are as follows.

```
VOWELS_SET = VOWELS.to_set
  #=> #<Set: {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"}> 

h = words.each_with_object({}) {|w,h| (h[(w.chars & VOWELS).to_set] ||= []) << w}
  #=> {#<Set: {"o", "a"}>=>["goat"],
  #    #<Set: {"a", "i", "o"}>=>["action"],
  #    #<Set: {"e", "a"}>=>["tear", "hear"],
  #    #<Set: {"i", "o", "u"}>=>["impromptu"],
  #    #<Set: {"i", "e"}>=>["tired"],
  #    #<Set: {"e", "u", "o"}>=>["europe"]}
```

It is seen that the keys of `h` are subsets of the five vowels. The values are arrays of elements of `words` (words) that contain the vowels given by the key and no others. The values therefore collectively form a partition of `words`. When the number of words is large one would expect `h` to have 31 keys (`2**5 - 1`).

We now loop through the key-value pairs of `h`. For each, with key `k` and value `v`, the set of missing vowels (`vowels_needed`) is determined, then we loop through those keys-value pairs `[kk, vv]` of `h` for which `kk` is a superset of `vowels_needed`. All combinations of elements of `v` and `vv` are then added to the array being returned (after an adjustment to avoid double-counting each pair of words).

Continuing,

```
enum = h.each_with_object([])
  #=> #<Enumerator: {#<Set: {"o", "a"}>=>["goat"],
  #                  #<Set: {"a", "i", "o"}>=>["action"],
  #                  ...
  #                  #<Set: {"e", "u", "o"}>=>["europe"]}: 
  #     each_with_object([])>
```

The first value is generated by `enum` and passed to the block, and the block variables are assigned values:

```
(k,v), a = enum.next
  #=> [[#<Set: {"o", "a"}>, ["goat"]], []]
```

See [Enumerator#next](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-next).

The individual variables are assigned values by [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition):

```
k #=> #<Set: {"o", "a"}> 
v #=> ["goat"] 
a #=> []
```

The block calculations are now performed.

```
vowels_needed = VOWELS_SET-k
  #=> #<Set: {"e", "i", "u"}> 
h.each do |kk,vv|
  next unless kk.superset?(vowels_needed)
  v.each {|w1| vv.each {|w2| a << "%s %s" % [w1, w2] if w1 < w2}}
end
```

The word "goat" (`v`) has vowels "o" and "a", so it can only be matched with words that contain vowels "e", "i" and "u" (and possibly "o" and/or "a"). The expression

```
next unless kk.superset?(vowels_needed)
```

skips those keys of `h` (`kk`) that are not supersets of `vowels_needed`. See [Set#superset?](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-superset-3F).

None of the words in `words` contain "e", "i" and "u" so the array `a` is unchanged.

The next element is now generated by `enum`, passed to the block and the block variables are assigned values:

```
(k,v), a = enum.next
  #=> [[#<Set: {"a", "i", "o"}>, ["action"]], []] 
k #=> #<Set: {"a", "i", "o"}> 
v #=> ["action"] 
a #=> []
```

The block calculation begins:

```
vowels_needed = VOWELS_SET-k
  #=> #<Set: {"e", "u"}>
```

We see that `h` has only one key-value pair for which the key is a superset of `vowels_needed`:

```
kk = %w|e u o|.to_set
  #=> #<Set: {"e", "u", "o"}> 
vv = ["europe"]
```

We therefore execute:

```
v.each {|w1| vv.each {|w2| a << "%s %s" % [w1, w2] if w1 < w2}}
```

which adds one element to `a`:

```
a #=> ["action europe"]
```

The clause `if w1 < w2` is to ensure that later in the calculations `"europe action"` is not added to `a`.

If `v` (words containing 'a', 'i' and 'u') and `vv` (words containing 'e', 'u' and 'o') had instead been:

```
v  #=> ["action", "notification"]
vv #=> ["europe", "route"]
```

we would have added `"action europe"`, `"action route"` and `"notification route"` to `a`. (`”europe notification”` would be added later, when `k #=> #<Set: {"e", "u", "o"}`.)

**Benchmark**

I benchmarked my method against others suggested using @theTinMan's *Fruity* benchmark code. The only differences were in the array of words to be tested and the addition of my method to the benchmark, which I named `cary`. For the array of words to be considered I selected 600 words at random from a file of English words on my computer:

```
words = IO.readlines('/usr/share/dict/words', chomp: true).sample(600)
words.first 10
  #=> ["posadaship", "explosively", "expensilation", "conservatively", "plaiting",
  #    "unpillared", "intertwinement", "nonsolidified", "uraemic", "underspend"]
```

This array was found to contain 46,436 pairs of words containing all five vowels.

The results were as shown below.

```
compare {
  _viktor { viktor(words) }
  _ttm1 { ttm1(words) }
  _ttm2 { ttm2(words) }
  _ttm3 { ttm3(words) }
  _cary { cary(words) }
}
```

```
Running each test once. Test will take about 44 seconds.
_cary is faster than _ttm3 by 5x ± 0.1
_ttm3 is faster than _viktor by 50.0% ± 1.0%
_viktor is faster than _ttm2 by 30.000000000000004% ± 1.0%
_ttm2 is faster than _ttm1 by 2.4x ± 0.1
```

I then compared `cary` with `ttm3` for 1,000 randomly selected words. This array was found to contain 125,068 pairs of words containing all five vowels. That result was as follows:

```
Running each test once. Test will take about 19 seconds.
_cary is faster than _ttm3 by 3x ± 1.0
```

To get a feel for the variability of the benchmark I ran this last comparison twice more, each with a new random selection of 1,000 words. That gave me the following results:

```
Running each test once. Test will take about 17 seconds.
_cary is faster than _ttm3 by 5x ± 1.0
```

```
Running each test once. Test will take about 18 seconds.
_cary is faster than _ttm3 by 4x ± 1.0
```

It is seen the there is considerable variation among the samples.

Answer (score 2):

You said pairs so I assume it's a combination of two elements. I've made a combination of each two elements in the array using the [`#combination`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/combination) method. Then I [`#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-select)-ed only those pairs that contain all vowels once they're joined. Finally, I made sure to join those pairs :

```
["goat", "action", "tear", "impromptu", "tired", "europe"]
.combination(2)
.select { |c| c.join('') =~ /\b(?=\w*?a)(?=\w*?e)(?=\w*?i)(?=\w*?o)(?=\w*?u)[a-zA-Z]+\b/ }
.map{ |w| w.join(' ') }

#=> ["action europe", "tear impromptu"]
```

The regex is from "[What is the regex to match the words containing all the vowels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54267095/what-is-the-regex-to-match-the-words-containing-all-the-vowels/54267325#54267325)".

Comment: See "[Don’t use “click here” and other common hyperlink mistakes](https://medium.com/@heyoka/dont-use-click-here-f32f445d1021)".

Comment: @theTinMan You mean "See [this](https://medium.com/@heyoka/dont-use-click-here-f32f445d1021)" ? Thanks for the tip, it is indeed a hard to break habit

Comment: It is until you look at it from the point of view of this site. We need accurate and useful Google searches, so accurate anchor link text is useful. Also, a link that is obscure is less likely to be clicked so it's less useful.

Comment: Hi @Viktor thank´s a lot for your help! I have not yet learned about regular expressions, but your solution got me thinking and I found a way to make my approach work!

Comment: @Viktor instead of using your regex in the block of .select, I throw c.join("") into the helper method from my code, getting back true if the joined pair contains all vowels. Not very clean, but at least I understand it entirely :)

Comment: @MaxFeldmann I've added a small explanation to the answer, let me know if something's unclear in my solution. If you're looking for a place to learn more Ruby and eventually Rails, I highly recommend [The Odin Project](https://www.theodinproject.com/) . Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Starting similarly to Viktor's, I'd use a simple test to see what vowels exist in the words and compare to whether they match `"aeiou"` after stripping duplicates and sorting them:

```rb
def ttm1(ary)
  ary.combination(2).select { |a| 
    a.join.scan(/[aeiou]/).uniq.sort.join == 'aeiou' 
  }.map { |a| a.join(' ') }
end
ttm1(words) # => ["action europe", "tear impromptu"]
```

Breaking it down so you can see what's happening.

```rb
["goat", "action", "tear", "impromptu", "tired", "europe"]  # => ["goat", "action", "tear", "impromptu", "tired", "europe"]
            .combination(2)                                 
            .select { |a| a                                 # => ["goat", "action"],        ["goat", "tear"],     ["goat", "impromptu"],     ["goat", "tired"],    ["goat", "europe"],             ["action", "tear"],        ["action", "impromptu"],        ["action", "tired"],       ["action", "europe"],                ["tear", "impromptu"],     ["tear", "tired"],    ["tear", "europe"],             ["impromptu", "tired"],    ["impromptu", "europe"],             ["tired", "europe"]
                .join                                       # => "goataction",              "goattear",           "goatimpromptu",           "goattired",          "goateurope",                   "actiontear",              "actionimpromptu",              "actiontired",             "actioneurope",                      "tearimpromptu",           "teartired",          "teareurope",                   "impromptutired",          "impromptueurope",                   "tiredeurope"
                .scan(/[aeiou]/)                            # => ["o", "a", "a", "i", "o"], ["o", "a", "e", "a"], ["o", "a", "i", "o", "u"], ["o", "a", "i", "e"], ["o", "a", "e", "u", "o", "e"], ["a", "i", "o", "e", "a"], ["a", "i", "o", "i", "o", "u"], ["a", "i", "o", "i", "e"], ["a", "i", "o", "e", "u", "o", "e"], ["e", "a", "i", "o", "u"], ["e", "a", "i", "e"], ["e", "a", "e", "u", "o", "e"], ["i", "o", "u", "i", "e"], ["i", "o", "u", "e", "u", "o", "e"], ["i", "e", "e", "u", "o", "e"]
                .uniq                                       # => ["o", "a", "i"],           ["o", "a", "e"],      ["o", "a", "i", "u"],      ["o", "a", "i", "e"], ["o", "a", "e", "u"],           ["a", "i", "o", "e"],      ["a", "i", "o", "u"],           ["a", "i", "o", "e"],      ["a", "i", "o", "e", "u"],           ["e", "a", "i", "o", "u"], ["e", "a", "i"],      ["e", "a", "u", "o"],           ["i", "o", "u", "e"],      ["i", "o", "u", "e"],                ["i", "e", "u", "o"]
                .sort                                       # => ["a", "i", "o"],           ["a", "e", "o"],      ["a", "i", "o", "u"],      ["a", "e", "i", "o"], ["a", "e", "o", "u"],           ["a", "e", "i", "o"],      ["a", "i", "o", "u"],           ["a", "e", "i", "o"],      ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"],           ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"], ["a", "e", "i"],      ["a", "e", "o", "u"],           ["e", "i", "o", "u"],      ["e", "i", "o", "u"],                ["e", "i", "o", "u"]
                .join == 'aeiou'                            # => false,                     false,                false,                     false,                false,                          false,                     false,                          false,                     true,                                true,                      false,                false,                          false,                     false,                               false
            }                                               # => [["action", "europe"], ["tear", "impromptu"]]
```

Looking at the code it was jumping through hoops to find whether all the vowels exist. Every time it checked it had to step through many methods before determining whether all the vowels were found; In other words it couldn't short-circuit and fail until the very end which isn't good.

This code will:

```rb
def ttm2(ary)
  ary.combination(2).select { |a| 
    str = a.join 
    str[/a/] && str[/e/] && str[/i/] && str[/o/] && str[/u/]
  }.map { |a| a.join(' ') }
end
ttm2(words) # => ["action europe", "tear impromptu"]
```

But I don't like using the regular expression engine this way as it's slower than doing a direct lookup, which lead to:

```rb
def ttm3(ary)
  ary.combination(2).select { |a| 
    str = a.join 
    str['a'] && str['e'] && str['i'] && str['o'] && str['u']
  }.map { |a| a.join(' ') }
end
```

Here's the benchmark:

```rb
require 'fruity'

words = ["goat", "action", "tear", "impromptu", "tired", "europe"]                                  

def viktor(ary)
  ary.combination(2)                                                                             
  .select { |c| c.join('') =~ /\b(?=\w*?a)(?=\w*?e)(?=\w*?i)(?=\w*?o)(?=\w*?u)[a-zA-Z]+\b/ }  
  .map{ |w| w.join(' ') }                                                                     
end
viktor(words) # => ["action europe", "tear impromptu"]

def ttm1(ary)
  ary.combination(2).select { |a| 
    a.join.scan(/[aeiou]/).uniq.sort.join == 'aeiou' 
  }.map { |a| a.join(' ') }
end
ttm1(words) # => ["action europe", "tear impromptu"]

def ttm2(ary)
  ary.combination(2).select { |a| 
    str = a.join 
    str[/a/] && str[/e/] && str[/i/] && str[/o/] && str[/u/]
  }.map { |a| a.join(' ') }
end
ttm2(words) # => ["action europe", "tear impromptu"]

def ttm3(ary)
  ary.combination(2).select { |a| 
    str = a.join 
    str['a'] && str['e'] && str['i'] && str['o'] && str['u']
  }.map { |a| a.join(' ') }
end
ttm3(words) # => ["action europe", "tear impromptu"]

compare {
  _viktor { viktor(words) }
  _ttm1 { ttm1(words) }
  _ttm2 { ttm2(words) }
  _ttm3 { ttm3(words) }
}
```

With the results:

```
# >> Running each test 256 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> _ttm3 is similar to _viktor
# >> _viktor is similar to _ttm2
# >> _ttm2 is faster than _ttm1 by 2x ± 0.1
```

Now, because this looks so much like a homework assignment, it's important to understand that schools are aware of Stack Overflow, and they look for students asking for help, so you probably don't want to reuse this code, especially not verbatim.

Comment: Thank you so much for the breakdown @theTinMan! It is indeed homework, but I have no school to teach me (unfortunately).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking homework-type questions here, as long as you show you put in the effort and ask a good question, which I think you did. I added a second piece of code to see what that'd do.

Comment: Clever! You can tweak your code by reordering `str['a'] && str['e'] && str['i'] && str['o'] && str['u']` to `str['u'] && str['i'] && str['o'] && str['a'] && str['e']`. [This wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency) reports that the average frequency of the letters 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o' and 'u' in English text is, respectively, 8.167%, 12.702%, 6.966%, 7.507% and 2.758%. You therefore should be able to short-circuit sooner, on average, by checking letters in order of their average frequency.